# Await issue for message in DM if the user sent a command in a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried so me code and didn't work for waiting messages so I wanna know how to wait for message in DM if the user sent a command in a channel using discord.py.

UPDATED

This is the last code which worked as example according to what the accepted answer!

````
async def command_name(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Send a message in DM.")

        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.guild is None

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        # Do something after they sent a DM```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) for this. You can write a custom `check` to see if it's a DM channel or not. The check is a function that returns `True` if your function should stop waiting, or `False` if it shouldn't. You only slightly have to modify the example from the docs to get your desired result:

```
@client.command()
async def command_name(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Send a message in DM.")

        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.guild is None

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        # Do something after they sent a DM
```